# Core Data Value returns Nil

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Hi i have been working with core data to store and retrieve some values(String only) from the core data. Here is how i am storing the values.

**The Function :**

```
public func saveStringValue(forKey: String, value: String) -> Bool{
    var saved = false
    if self.entityName != nil && self.appDelegate != nil{
        let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context != nil{
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: self.entityName!, in: context!)
            let entityHandle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context!)
            entityHandle.setValue(value, forKey: forKey)
            do{
                try context?.save()
                saved = true
            }catch let error as NSError{
                saved = false
                print("Error : \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    return saved 
}
```

**Here is how i call it**

```
let historyManager = HistoryManager(entity: "SearchHistory")
        let titleInserted = historyManager.saveStringValue(forKey: "title", value: book.title!)
        if(titleInserted == true)
        {
            print("Title Inserted to Entity")
        }

        if let image = book.imageUrl{
            let imageInserted = historyManager.saveStringValue(forKey: "image", value: image)
            if imageInserted == true{
                print("Image Url Inserted to Entity")
            }
        }
```

I can see in the console printed that

1. Title inserted into entity
2. ImageInserted Into entity

Here is the code to retrieve the value from core data store

```
public func fetchAll() -> [Book]{
    var books = [Book]()
    let context = self.appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: self.entityName!)
    //let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SearchHistory> = SearchHistory.fetchRequest()

    do{
        let fetchedBooks = try context?.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for aBook in fetchedBooks!{
            if let title = aBook.value(forKey: "title"){
                let book = Book(title: title as! String)
                if let im = aBook.value(forKey: "image"){

                    book.imageUrl = im as! String
                    print("ImageUrl : \(im) : ")
                }
                else{
                    print("No Value for key : image")
                }
                books.append(book)
            }


        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print("Fetch Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    print("Books : \(books.count)")
    return books
}
```

But when i run the code to retrieve the book imageUrl it returns nil and prints

1. No value for key : image
   It retrieves the title but not the imageUrl. 
   Can you help me through this problem or point me to the right direction. And please do post the reason why i was getting this problem and how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `saveStringValue` creates a new `NSManagedObject` instance each time you call it.

The first time you call `saveStringValue` you will create a `SearchHistory` object that has a `title` but no `image`.  The second time you call it you will create another `SearchHistory` object with an `image` value but no `title`.

In my opinion, your `saveStringValue` function is unnecessary. Assuming your code is based on a template that resulted from clicking "use Core Data" in Xcode, you will have a `SearchHistory` class available and you can use something like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let newHistory = SearchHistory(context: context)

newHistory.title = book.title
newHistory.image = book.imageUrl

appDelegate.saveContext()
```

Comment: Why did you write let newHistory = SearchHistory(context: Context)                    There is no class SearchHistory.

Comment: Xcode automatically creates classes for your Core Data entities unless you turn off this option in the core data model.